# Make/score a goal (AmE)

Tags: word-usage, american-english

What is more common in AE?

> He ***made*** a goal.
>
> He ***scored*** a goal.

So is "made" or "score" used in soccer? I mean which one is more  common?

Comment: I can't comment from the AmE perspective, but some Google phrase searching suggests that *scored* is more common; there are more results for *made*, but the first couple of pages is mostly cases where there's one or more words after *goal* that make it quite a different thing - like "make a goal kick" or "make a goal scoring start to the season".

Comment: score is the official term used in American soccer games.

Answer (score 2):

The commentators and talking heads say scored, without necessarily saying the word goal.
When they are excited, they say something like: "And he scored!"

The only problem with this is that it doesn't really allow for those long
GOALLLLLLL!! one hears in Spanish and Portuguese. A pity, really. They could, if wanted to, still yell that out but they don't.

The full phrase in AmE is to score a goal.

And more recently, one hears a lot of golazos when stars like Messie are playing and the shots are daring or difficult.

Sometimes, in a long,fast speech on football (soccer), one might hear make a goal, too.

I live in the States and watch a lot of soccer on TV but my favorite commentator is Englishman Ray Hudson, who is known for his language. He recently said that some play or other was "as a sloppy as a soup sandwich."

Comment: I am very reassured to hear that  I know that you Americans use some strange terms around one of our (Brits') national sports, but the idea of "making a goal" just seems strange to me. And yeah, we have a very different attitude to sports commentary. How they fill the time during cricket commentary can get very amusing. Or bewildering, depending on how you take it. I once heard them comparing the curries made by different player's mothers. That was weird.

Comment: We sometimes say *got a goal*, too.

Comment: I would think you can *make* a goal in that it's an action you are causing to be completed, like making a pass, or making an assist, or making an interception. Most of the time, of course, you're interested in the effect on the score, hence *score a basket*, *score a hat trick*, *scored a run*, and so on would be preferable, but I don't myself object to *make*.

Comment: @snailboat clinched a goal. kicked it in. Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @choster: I can't say why, but we (Brits) just wouldn't use it in that way, in my experience. I think people might use *made the conversion* in rugby, and we certainly use the idiom *made it*, but I don't think we would use it for a goal. I think *made a try* gets used in rugby, too, though not that often.

Comment: @SamBC The Telegraph: His run had **made the goal** but as Mallorca opened up in the pursuit of an equaliser.....among others. Examiner Live: Here, we break down the move that **made the goal** and see exactly why the 36-year-old German was so angry.

Comment: @Lambie: Ah, yes, a *thing* (plan, action, etc) will make a goal, though that still feels a little unusual to me. The existence of examples doesn't show something isn't *unusual*. A person making a goal, in the sense of soccer, and not meaning "got as far as the goal", is even stranger.